# Altering A table to add an extra column (rank) with a Mysql DENSE_RANK() function from some details (id, subject, points)

Tags: mysql

id        subject       points   Rank
joe       maths         70        1
Mike      maths         60        2
Sarah     maths         40        3
mike      English       80        1
Sarah     English       65        2
joe       English       55        3
Sarah     Chemistry     80        1
Mike      Chemistry     60        2
joe       Chemistry     43        3

I was able to query this in mysql but i want to store the rank column in the  table (grades) using the ALTER command 
 i tried 
ALTER TABLE grades 
ADD COLUMN Rank
GENERATE ALWAYS AS
DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY subjects ORDER BY points DESC)
ORDER BY id, 
Rank

but did not work 
Hope i could find some help out there

Comment: You cannot have calculated column in such manner. You could use view instead.

Comment: Ok Thanks, What if i just want to add only the new rank column to the existing table grade

Comment: You should not store easily derived columns.

Comment: If you resist on doing this: what's the problem?

Comment: thanks to all the VIEW actually worked